# Error (command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1) when trying to install OpenDR

Tags: python, libraries

I am a python beginner and I'm currently trying to run smpl, however I need to download OpenDR to do so. I have installed homebrew and command line tools and checked that I have gcc downloaded. I am pretty stumped at this point on how to proceed. I attached the full error code I am receiving. Any help at this point would really be appreciated.

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/jonasdixon/opt/anaconda3/envs/py27/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/bl/vpm7gmwx2zqdqf04vddhv6180000gn/T/pip-install-G9YeQJ/opendr/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/bl/vpm7gmwx2zqdqf04vddhv6180000gn/T/pip-install-G9YeQJ/opendr/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/bl/vpm7gmwx2zqdqf04vddhv6180000gn/T/pip-wheel-CZsgRX --python-tag cp27
       cwd: /private/var/folders/bl/vpm7gmwx2zqdqf04vddhv6180000gn/T/pip-install-G9YeQJ/opendr/
  Complete output (87 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
  copying opendr/test_renderer.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
  copying opendr/test_camera.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
  copying opendr/version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
  copying opendr/cvwrap.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
  copying opendr/slider_demo.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
  copying opendr/renderer.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
  copying opendr/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
  copying opendr/everything.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
  copying opendr/test_sh.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
  copying opendr/util_tests.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
  copying opendr/lighting.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
  copying opendr/camera.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
  copying opendr/occlusion_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
  copying opendr/common.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
  copying opendr/utils.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
  copying opendr/geometry.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
  copying opendr/topology.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
  copying opendr/test_depth_renderer.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
  copying opendr/simple.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
  copying opendr/dummy.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
  copying opendr/test_geometry.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
  copying opendr/serialization.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
  copying opendr/filters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr/contexts
  copying opendr/contexts/_constants.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr/contexts
  copying opendr/contexts/draw_triangle_shaders_3_2.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr/contexts
  copying opendr/contexts/fix_warnings.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr/contexts
  copying opendr/contexts/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr/contexts
  copying opendr/contexts/autogen.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr/contexts
  copying opendr/contexts/draw_triangle_shaders_2_1.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr/contexts
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr/test_dr
  copying opendr/test_dr/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr/test_dr
  running build_ext
  building 'opendr.contexts.ctx_mac' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr/contexts
  gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -I/Users/jonasdixon/opt/anaconda3/envs/py27/include -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Iopendr/contexts -I. -I/Users/jonasdixon/opt/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Users/jonasdixon/opt/anaconda3/envs/py27/include/python2.7 -c opendr/contexts/ctx_mac.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr/contexts/ctx_mac.o -Qunused-arguments
  In file included from opendr/contexts/ctx_mac.c:630:
  In file included from /Users/jonasdixon/opt/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4:
  In file included from /Users/jonasdixon/opt/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:12:
  In file included from /Users/jonasdixon/opt/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1824:
  /Users/jonasdixon/opt/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:17:2: warning: "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with "          "#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-W#warnings]
  #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " \
   ^
  opendr/contexts/ctx_mac.c:3498:3: error: implicit declaration of function 'glGenVertexArrays' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    glGenVertexArrays(__pyx_v_n, (&(*__Pyx_BufPtrStrided1d(unsigned int *, __pyx_pybuffernd_arr.rcbuffer->pybuffer.buf, __pyx_t_11, __pyx_pybuffernd_arr.diminfo[0].strides))));
    ^
  opendr/contexts/ctx_mac.c:3498:3: note: did you mean 'glGenVertexArraysAPPLE'?
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers/glext.h:3407:13: note: 'glGenVertexArraysAPPLE' declared here
  extern void glGenVertexArraysAPPLE(GLsizei n, GLuint *ids);
              ^
  opendr/contexts/ctx_mac.c:3637:3: error: implicit declaration of function 'glBindFragDataLocation' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    glBindFragDataLocation(__pyx_v_program, __pyx_v_color, __pyx_v_name);
    ^
  opendr/contexts/ctx_mac.c:3637:3: note: did you mean 'glBindFragDataLocationEXT'?
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers/glext.h:3075:13: note: 'glBindFragDataLocationEXT' declared here
  extern void glBindFragDataLocationEXT(GLuint program, GLuint colorNumber, const GLchar *name);
              ^
  opendr/contexts/ctx_mac.c:4149:3: error: implicit declaration of function 'glClearBufferfv' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    glClearBufferfv(__pyx_v_buffer, __pyx_v_drawbuffer, ((GLfloat *)__pyx_v_value->data));
    ^
  opendr/contexts/ctx_mac.c:4149:3: note: did you mean 'glReadBuffer'?
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers/gl.h:2651:13: note: 'glReadBuffer' declared here
  extern void glReadBuffer (GLenum mode) OPENGL_DEPRECATED(10.0, 10.14);
              ^
  opendr/contexts/ctx_mac.c:12787:49: warning: passing 'char **' to parameter of type 'const GLchar *const *' (aka 'const char *const *') discards qualifiers in nested pointer types [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
    glShaderSource(__pyx_v_shader, __pyx_v_count, (&__pyx_v_s), (&__pyx_v_len));
                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers/gl.h:2926:80: note: passing argument to parameter 'string' here
  extern void glShaderSource (GLuint shader, GLsizei count, const GLchar* const *string, const GLint *length) OPENGL_DEPRECATED(10.0, 10.14);
                                                                                 ^
  opendr/contexts/ctx_mac.c:13017:3: error: implicit declaration of function 'glBindVertexArray' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    glBindVertexArray(__pyx_v_array);
    ^
  opendr/contexts/ctx_mac.c:13017:3: note: did you mean 'glBindVertexArrayAPPLE'?
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers/glext.h:3405:13: note: 'glBindVertexArrayAPPLE' declared here
  extern void glBindVertexArrayAPPLE(GLuint id);
              ^
  2 warnings and 4 errors generated.
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for opendr
  Running setup.py clean for opendr
Failed to build opendr
Installing collected packages: opendr
  Running setup.py install for opendr ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/jonasdixon/opt/anaconda3/envs/py27/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/bl/vpm7gmwx2zqdqf04vddhv6180000gn/T/pip-install-G9YeQJ/opendr/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/bl/vpm7gmwx2zqdqf04vddhv6180000gn/T/pip-install-G9YeQJ/opendr/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/bl/vpm7gmwx2zqdqf04vddhv6180000gn/T/pip-record-FyeaO3/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: /private/var/folders/bl/vpm7gmwx2zqdqf04vddhv6180000gn/T/pip-install-G9YeQJ/opendr/
    Complete output (87 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
    copying opendr/test_renderer.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
    copying opendr/test_camera.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
    copying opendr/version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
    copying opendr/cvwrap.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
    copying opendr/slider_demo.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
    copying opendr/renderer.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
    copying opendr/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
    copying opendr/everything.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
    copying opendr/test_sh.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
    copying opendr/util_tests.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
    copying opendr/lighting.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
    copying opendr/camera.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
    copying opendr/occlusion_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
    copying opendr/common.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
    copying opendr/utils.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
    copying opendr/geometry.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
    copying opendr/topology.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
    copying opendr/test_depth_renderer.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
    copying opendr/simple.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
    copying opendr/dummy.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
    copying opendr/test_geometry.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
    copying opendr/serialization.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
    copying opendr/filters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr/contexts
    copying opendr/contexts/_constants.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr/contexts
    copying opendr/contexts/draw_triangle_shaders_3_2.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr/contexts
    copying opendr/contexts/fix_warnings.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr/contexts
    copying opendr/contexts/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr/contexts
    copying opendr/contexts/autogen.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr/contexts
    copying opendr/contexts/draw_triangle_shaders_2_1.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr/contexts
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr/test_dr
    copying opendr/test_dr/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr/test_dr
    running build_ext
    building 'opendr.contexts.ctx_mac' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr/contexts
    gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -I/Users/jonasdixon/opt/anaconda3/envs/py27/include -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Iopendr/contexts -I. -I/Users/jonasdixon/opt/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Users/jonasdixon/opt/anaconda3/envs/py27/include/python2.7 -c opendr/contexts/ctx_mac.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/opendr/contexts/ctx_mac.o -Qunused-arguments
    In file included from opendr/contexts/ctx_mac.c:630:
    In file included from /Users/jonasdixon/opt/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4:
    In file included from /Users/jonasdixon/opt/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:12:
    In file included from /Users/jonasdixon/opt/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1824:
    /Users/jonasdixon/opt/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:17:2: warning: "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with "          "#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-W#warnings]
    #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " \
     ^
    opendr/contexts/ctx_mac.c:3498:3: error: implicit declaration of function 'glGenVertexArrays' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
      glGenVertexArrays(__pyx_v_n, (&(*__Pyx_BufPtrStrided1d(unsigned int *, __pyx_pybuffernd_arr.rcbuffer->pybuffer.buf, __pyx_t_11, __pyx_pybuffernd_arr.diminfo[0].strides))));
      ^
    opendr/contexts/ctx_mac.c:3498:3: note: did you mean 'glGenVertexArraysAPPLE'?
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers/glext.h:3407:13: note: 'glGenVertexArraysAPPLE' declared here
    extern void glGenVertexArraysAPPLE(GLsizei n, GLuint *ids);
                ^
    opendr/contexts/ctx_mac.c:3637:3: error: implicit declaration of function 'glBindFragDataLocation' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
      glBindFragDataLocation(__pyx_v_program, __pyx_v_color, __pyx_v_name);
      ^
    opendr/contexts/ctx_mac.c:3637:3: note: did you mean 'glBindFragDataLocationEXT'?
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers/glext.h:3075:13: note: 'glBindFragDataLocationEXT' declared here
    extern void glBindFragDataLocationEXT(GLuint program, GLuint colorNumber, const GLchar *name);
                ^
    opendr/contexts/ctx_mac.c:4149:3: error: implicit declaration of function 'glClearBufferfv' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
      glClearBufferfv(__pyx_v_buffer, __pyx_v_drawbuffer, ((GLfloat *)__pyx_v_value->data));
      ^
    opendr/contexts/ctx_mac.c:4149:3: note: did you mean 'glReadBuffer'?
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers/gl.h:2651:13: note: 'glReadBuffer' declared here
    extern void glReadBuffer (GLenum mode) OPENGL_DEPRECATED(10.0, 10.14);
                ^
    opendr/contexts/ctx_mac.c:12787:49: warning: passing 'char **' to parameter of type 'const GLchar *const *' (aka 'const char *const *') discards qualifiers in nested pointer types [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
      glShaderSource(__pyx_v_shader, __pyx_v_count, (&__pyx_v_s), (&__pyx_v_len));
                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers/gl.h:2926:80: note: passing argument to parameter 'string' here
    extern void glShaderSource (GLuint shader, GLsizei count, const GLchar* const *string, const GLint *length) OPENGL_DEPRECATED(10.0, 10.14);
                                                                                   ^
    opendr/contexts/ctx_mac.c:13017:3: error: implicit declaration of function 'glBindVertexArray' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
      glBindVertexArray(__pyx_v_array);
      ^
    opendr/contexts/ctx_mac.c:13017:3: note: did you mean 'glBindVertexArrayAPPLE'?
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers/glext.h:3405:13: note: 'glBindVertexArrayAPPLE' declared here
    extern void glBindVertexArrayAPPLE(GLuint id);
                ^
    2 warnings and 4 errors generated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/jonasdixon/opt/anaconda3/envs/py27/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/bl/vpm7gmwx2zqdqf04vddhv6180000gn/T/pip-install-G9YeQJ/opendr/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/bl/vpm7gmwx2zqdqf04vddhv6180000gn/T/pip-install-G9YeQJ/opendr/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/bl/vpm7gmwx2zqdqf04vddhv6180000gn/T/pip-record-FyeaO3/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want a TLDR, skip to the section about the solution. I tried to document my problem solving process and I hope that it'll be useful for you.

## Investigation

Let's analyze your error output and try to solve this issue. Quickly glossing over the output, it looks like this blob is the relevant one:

```
   /Users/jonasdixon/opt/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:17:2: warning: "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with "          "#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-W#warnings]
    #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " \
     ^
    opendr/contexts/ctx_mac.c:3498:3: error: implicit declaration of function 'glGenVertexArrays' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
      glGenVertexArrays(__pyx_v_n, (&(*__Pyx_BufPtrStrided1d(unsigned int *, __pyx_pybuffernd_arr.rcbuffer->pybuffer.buf, __pyx_t_11, __pyx_pybuffernd_arr.diminfo[0].strides))));
      ^
    opendr/contexts/ctx_mac.c:3498:3: note: did you mean 'glGenVertexArraysAPPLE'?
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers/glext.h:3407:13: note: 'glGenVertexArraysAPPLE' declared here
    extern void glGenVertexArraysAPPLE(GLsizei n, GLuint *ids);
                ^
    opendr/contexts/ctx_mac.c:3637:3: error: implicit declaration of function 'glBindFragDataLocation' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
      glBindFragDataLocation(__pyx_v_program, __pyx_v_color, __pyx_v_name);
      ^
    opendr/contexts/ctx_mac.c:3637:3: note: did you mean 'glBindFragDataLocationEXT'?
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers/glext.h:3075:13: note: 'glBindFragDataLocationEXT' declared here
    extern void glBindFragDataLocationEXT(GLuint program, GLuint colorNumber, const GLchar *name);
                ^
    opendr/contexts/ctx_mac.c:4149:3: error: implicit declaration of function 'glClearBufferfv' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
      glClearBufferfv(__pyx_v_buffer, __pyx_v_drawbuffer, ((GLfloat *)__pyx_v_value->data));
      ^
    opendr/contexts/ctx_mac.c:4149:3: note: did you mean 'glReadBuffer'?
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers/gl.h:2651:13: note: 'glReadBuffer' declared here
    extern void glReadBuffer (GLenum mode) OPENGL_DEPRECATED(10.0, 10.14);
                ^
    opendr/contexts/ctx_mac.c:12787:49: warning: passing 'char **' to parameter of type 'const GLchar *const *' (aka 'const char *const *') discards qualifiers in nested pointer types [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
      glShaderSource(__pyx_v_shader, __pyx_v_count, (&__pyx_v_s), (&__pyx_v_len));
                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers/gl.h:2926:80: note: passing argument to parameter 'string' here
    extern void glShaderSource (GLuint shader, GLsizei count, const GLchar* const *string, const GLint *length) OPENGL_DEPRECATED(10.0, 10.14);
                                                                                   ^
    opendr/contexts/ctx_mac.c:13017:3: error: implicit declaration of function 'glBindVertexArray' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
      glBindVertexArray(__pyx_v_array);
      ^
    opendr/contexts/ctx_mac.c:13017:3: note: did you mean 'glBindVertexArrayAPPLE'?
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers/glext.h:3405:13: note: 'glBindVertexArrayAPPLE' declared here
    extern void glBindVertexArrayAPPLE(GLuint id);
                ^
    2 warnings and 4 errors generated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

At the bottom we can see that `gcc`, which is the default C compiler on many platforms, failed with 4 errors. Looking over the output we can identify a common reason for those:

`error: implicit declaration of function 'glBindVertexArray' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]`

Googling it yields [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25250305/implicit-declaration-of-function-glbindvertexarrayoes-is-invalid-in-c99), but we probably don't want to modify code that we just downloaded from the internet and that we don't understand. The third google link is [this post](https://community.khronos.org/t/implicit-declaration-warnings/73600) on the Khronos forums, where our errors are... warnings?

Further investigation or some intuition may reveal that the `[-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]` command line switches from the output are significant. `-Wimplicit-function-declaration` generates the warnings, and `-Werror` turns warnings into errors. This explains our behavior... now we need to fix it.

Now there are a few options:

1. Change the compiler to a compatible one. We don't know which one is compatible and it won't work for sure.
2. Change the definition of -Werror. To be honest, I'm not quite sure how to do that.
3. Remove the `-Wall` flag from the compilation command, or negate it somehow.

## The Solution

I think that option 3 is best. I have no way to model this, but this is what I suggest you do:

1. Download the `opendr` package separately, using pip.
2. Open [setup.py](https://github.com/mattloper/opendr/blob/master/setup.py), and modify line 132 and 133 to add `-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration`. See more details [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html).
3. Install the package using `setup.py` - it's a common installation scheme for python packages, so there's plenty of documentation. Compilation should work now :)

I realize this is quite complex and bruteforce, but I think that it will solve the problem. If anyone has a better solution, I'd love to hear about it.

Additionally, you can open an issue on the github repository, or even modify the code so that it's correct and those warnings aren't generated. It'll take more effort, but it's a really cool way to start contributing to open source and it'll save everyone the trouble :)

## Appendix

You might ask yourself how this EVER compiled on anyone's computer. The answer is simple - the `-Wall` switch that is provided for compilation doesn't actually enable all warnings, and it's different between compilers, and even compiler versions. I'm not 100% sure if this is the case here, but it sure looks like it. There's decent discussion about this [on Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=15400396).